# Customer admin grid new customer add where form customer attribute get in ui grid in magento2?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-grid

In default [image]

Account Information label working but in my side it's not display

see:
[image]

Do anyone know the flow for it?

Comment: have u created new module?

Comment: yes my custom module i have customer_form.xml for 2 custom tabs which shows in image

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not working is because it's getting overwritten in the luma theme.

If you want to change that, create a theme that extends the luma theme and change it there.

Check the file under theme-luma/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

If you change it there it will work, but.. you don't wanna change that directly in the luma theme.. ;)

Create a custom theme and activate it. Make sure it's a child of the luma theme

```
theme.xml

<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>My new super awesome fabulous theme!</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
then create the file in your new theme Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml with these contents :

customer_account.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string"
                         translate="true">Awesome new dashboard
               </argument>
           </arguments>
       </referenceBlock>
       <!-- Change Account information -->
       <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string"
                         translate="true">My Profile</argument>
           </arguments>
       </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: But customer_account.xml is working frontside and error in adminside
Are we on same page?